# Stop reading when empty value is found

Tags: c#, csv

I have following code:

```
if (!lines1.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("File is empty!", "");
    return;
}

foreach (var line1 in lines1)
{
    var fields1 = line1.Split(new Char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    date1.Add(fields1[0].Trim('\"'));
    if (fields1.Length > 1)
        data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields1[1].Trim('\"'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

and a csv file which contains entries like:

```
"Date";"Value1";"Value2","Value3"
20.01.2001;35.930;12.341;12,98;
```

(and so on)

This works - so it reads the file and store the values of the first two columns in two separate lists. But now it is possible that I have empty entries in "Value2" at the end. What my code does is - he just skips the empty entry and stores the value of "Value2" but I would like that he just stops copying the data into the List and continues. What to do?

When I try:
if (fields1.Length > 1 && (!(line1.Contains(""))))

it skips the data.Add line but every time! I just want that he skips it if a sequence like
20.01.2002;;23.098; (...) appears

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just don't `RemoveEmptyEntries` and handle the logic

Comment: Please clarify, is your goal to stop reading when an empty line is found?

Comment: You should change the title because you are not looking for an empty line but empty value in a line.

Answer (score 0):

simple,

```
foreach (var line1 in lines1)
{
     if (string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace(line1))
     {
         break;
     }

     var fields1 = line1.Split(
         new Char[] { ';' },
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     date1.Add(fields1[0].Trim('\"'));
     if (fields1.Length > 1)
     {
         data.Add(
             Convert.ToDouble(fields1[1].Trim('\"'),
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
     }
}
```

This breaks the loop (stops reading) when an empty line is found.

Comment: Hopefully the .NET version he uses already supports 'string.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace'

Comment: @Forlan07 unless the OP states otherwise, assume the latest framework version.

Comment: I tried string.IsNullOrEmpty but when I put that after if(fields1.Length>0) I get a formatException

Comment: @uzi42tmp best to put it where I show you. At the start. If the lines empty, whats the point in splitting it?

Comment: problem is that the date is never empty and I would to take its values. so it should skip the data List and continue to write into the date List

Comment: @Jodrell - I think the confusion is that the 3rd element in `fields1` (referred to as "value2" in the question) can be empty rather than the whole line so the check needs to be moved to `fields1[2]`.

Comment: If empty lines exists in the middle of the file this will be wrong though. If so, just change the "break" to "continue".

Comment: No they doesn't exist in the middle but he does not skip anything. He should add an element to the date List and if "value1" is empty then just continue to add the date element and so on - so it could be that he reads 10 date values and just 3 data values because the data values are empty after the third position

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to do. But as I understand you want to stop adding values to both lists when you get to a row with an empty cell of column two.

If that is the case just replace

```
if (fields1.Length > 1)
    data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields1[1].Trim('\"'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

with

```
if (fields1.Length == 1) break;
data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields1[1].Trim('\"'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

[EDIT1]

From the comments of other answers I think I understand what you want to do. You would like to add all dates but stop adding values to list as soon as you get to an empty value.
If this is the case than do this:

```
bool shouldBeAddingValues = true;
foreach (var line1 in lines1)
{
    var fields1 = line1.Split(new Char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    date1.Add(fields1[0].Trim('\"'));
    shouldBeAddingValues &= fields1.Length > 1;
    if (shouldBeAddingValues)
        data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(fields1[1].Trim('\"'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

[EDIT2]

From your edit I can finally see what you are trying to do. As Yorye Nathan commented you should remove RemoveEmptyEntries. So the code should be:

```
foreach (var line1 in lines1)
{
    var fields1 = line1.Split(new Char[] { ';' });
    date1.Add(fields1[0].Trim('\"'));
    string val = fields1[1].Trim('\"');
    if (val != "")
        data.Add(Convert.ToDouble(val, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Comment: No. just stop adding elements to the second list if it reads an empty value. Tried " if (fields1.Length > 1 && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line1)))" but that doesnt work - he continues reading the second column